# Remover tags geradas no final da string de um Editor de Texto

Tags: python, regex, django, replace

Estou usando um editor de texto e assim como outros que já usei, ele sempre gera algumas tags inuteis que gostaria de remover. Eu consigo remover a última, porem as vezes ele gera mais de uma vez.

Meu código:

```
def remove_useless_tags(message):
    message = message.replace("<p><br/></p>", "") \
                .replace("<p></p>", "") \
                .replace("<p><b><br/></b></p>", "")
    # .replace("<p><br></p>", "")
    if message[-11:] == "<p><br></p>":
        message = message[:-11]
    return message
```

Quando aparece uma string dessa forma: `<p>Olá</p><p><br></p>` ele consegue remover o `<p><br></p>` do final. Porém as vezes vem textos nesse formato:

```
<p>Olá</p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
<p>Olá</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

Gostaria de remover todos os `<p><br></p>` do final da string. Lembrando que existe alguns `<p><br></p>` que estão no meio da frase que **não podem ser removidos**. Eles são "enters" que o usuário mesmo coloca quando vai escrever. O problema são os "enters" finais, que são desnecessários porém comprometem o layout.

Acredito que dê para resolver com regex, porém preciso de uma ajuda com isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você precisa pegar exatamente uma sequencia no final do texto você pode usar o token `$`, sua regex só precisa de um limitador e um quantificador na sequencia que você quer capturar, pra você não precisar ficar repetindo o comando de substituição.

Então recomendo que você use essa Regex `(<p><br><\/p>)*?$` com a função [re.sub(pattern, substitution, string)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), já que o replace não funciona com regex..

**Aplicação no seu código:**

```
import re
[...]
def remove_useless_tags(message):
    result = re.sub('(<p><br><\/p>)*?$', "", message)

    return result
```

**Explicação da Regex**

```
(<p><br><\/p>)*?$
```

- `(<p><br><\/p>)` > Sequencia que você quer capturar.
- `*?` > Quantificador lazy, vai capturar 0 ou + sequencias.
- `$` > Sinaliza que só pode capturar no fim da string.

[Aqui também tem um teste da Regex](https://regex101.com/r/izWEY1/2)

Comment: Se eu quisesse também remover esses conteúdos do inicio da string eu colocaria no começo o `$`? Dessa forma: `$(<p><br><\/p>)*?` ?

Comment: @GuilhermeIA A lógica é essa mesmo, só que o caractere que sinaliza o início de string em regex é `^`, então ficaria `^(<p><br><\/p>)*?`. Se quiser usar a regex da resposta e essa no mesmo padrão para tirar a repetição tanto do começo como do final ficaria assim:  `^(<p><br><\/p>)*|(<p><br><\/p>)*?$`